# How to redirect a stream to simple Java application?

Tags: java, bash, pipe

I have a file `data.txt`. Its content is:

```
a b c
d e f
```

I also have Java code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("size: " + args.length);
        for (String arg : args) {
            System.out.println("arg: " + arg);
        }
    }
}
```

And a script `run`:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar test.jar "$@"
```

I want to redirect a file as stream to my app.

I tried the following:

```
cat data.txt | ./run
```

Which gave me:

```
size: 0
```

But I want to see:

```
size: 6
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Because I want to pass a file to my app in a way like this.

Comment: Why don't you try it? Then you will see if it works.

Comment: You can redirect a file, but it redirects to `System.in`, not to the command line arguments. Just read `System.in` as if it was from a user.

Comment: @barbara That's clear from your question. What I meant was why can't you just pass the file name as a command line argument to your Java program instead? Any specific reason you want to use a pipe?

Comment: Simply asking "_is it possible?"_ may not be the best approach.  You should update your quesiton with what happened when you tried to run the code you showed

Comment: I don't think this is an unreasonable question to ask - a standard command-line tool exists to do exactly this (`xargs`), just not specifically for Java.

Comment: @AndyTurner Reasonable perhaps, but it is currently not properly worded and does not explain why the attempted code does not work, nor does it even state that it fails, which is probably the reason for downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke with `xargs` to concatenate the contents of stdin with the command line:

```
cat data.txt | xargs ./run
```

Depending upon the value of `$IFS`, this may be equivalent to:

```
./run a b c d e f
```